# Переклад словосполучення "nanny state"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

"[Nanny state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanny_state)" - вислів, який вживається стосовно уряду, який занадто опікується своїми співгромадянами або обмежує можливість зробити той чи інший вибір (мені навели приклад, що це може бути прийнятя закону про заборону курити майже на території всієї країни).

[Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/nanny%20state), [Гугл](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/nanny%20state) та [Мета](http://translate.meta.ua/ua/#) з перекладом ніяк не допомогли (зазначу, що слово "nanny" перекладається як "няня", а "state" - це держава).

Чи можливо це взагалі перекласти? Чи найкращим варіантом буде використати описовий переклад?

Answer (score 1):

Прямий переклад дозволяє вивести значення словосполучення на інтуїтивний рівень.

Словосполучення "**уряд-нянька**" вже використовують:

1. [ukr.segodnya.ua](https://ukr.segodnya.ua/lifestyle/fun/singapur-recept-procvetayushchego-gosudarstva-ot-li-kuan-yu-614925.html):

> Він був явним прихильником теорії "сильної руки" (яку в самому
>   Сінгапурі критики називають "**уряд-нянька**") і вважав, що Захід занадто
>   ліберальний в багатьох питаннях, розплачуючись на це відсутністю
>   порядку.

2. і [maidan.org.ua](http://maidan.org.ua/arch/oldosvita/1108157424.html):

> А про якусь особливу соціальну орієнтацію держави переважна більшість
>   американців думає дуже негативно. Вони кажуть, "нам не потрібний
>   **уряд-нянька**" ("nanny government").

Вживання форми "нянька", а не просто "няня", доцільне, бо саме перший варіант має неґативні конотації, пов'язані з надмірною опікою, яка так не подобається дітям.

Аналоґічно з висловом "[**держава-нянька**](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3295j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)":

1. [Day.kyiv.ua](https://day.kyiv.ua/uk/article/panorama-dnya/kuveytska-derzhava-nyanka):

> І в Україні багато хто знає, що маленька, але заможна країна Перської затоки Кувейт — справжня «**держава-нянька**».

2. [Tsn.ua](https://tsn.ua/blogi/themes/zhittya/yak-tebe-ne-lyubiti-angliyske-rizdvo-1070325.html):

> Велика Британія — це **держава-нянька**, і вона такою є десятиліття, якщо не століття.

Поки вживаніший вислів "держава-нянька" (31 результат в ґуґлі проти двох), але на рівні таких чисел ми ще не можемо робити жодних висновків про те, який з них краще прижився в українській мові.